# How to export SharePoint Online list and import into a new tennant

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, export

Is there any way to export SharePoint Online lists and import into an another site?

There was an option for that in on-prem installations but I did not find any in SherPoint Online.

(I need something like a file what can be saved and published in an another SP site, this is how the SharePoint designer worked.)

Answer (score 1):

There are some options for your reference:

1. Use "Save list as template" and include content, then upload to destination site list template, then create a new list using this template.
2. Use Third-party tool as ShareGate to migrate the list.

   Reference: [Copy a List in SharePoint or Office 365](https://sharegate.com/blog/copy-list-in-sharepoint-to-office365-tool)
3. Use PowerShell and CSOM to go through the source list and add items to destination.

   Reference: [Copy Sharepoint list items to another list with Powershell and PnP](https://lazyadmin.nl/it/copy-sharepoint-list-items-to-another-list-with-powershell-and-pnp/)

Comment: I am sorry but there is no option for saving list as template on SharePoint Online
https://pasteboard.co/Ikr1SIB.png